# Run .NET Framework 4.6.2 without Runtime framework?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, runtime

Can I build a .NET Framework 4.6.2 application so that it doesn't require the runtime framework installed on the client machine running the application?

Comment: I'm afraid not, you need to move to .NET 6 for that

Comment: There is .Net native, but Single file deployment in .Net core 3+ is probably a much more appropriate solution.